# How can I make a border only appear on the top?

Tags: css, border

How can I make the border only appear on the top when I hover over it?
Code:

```
 a:hover {
    border-top: 3px white;
    border-style: solid;
 }
```

It makes the border still appear on all sides, but I want it to appear only on top.

Comment: Your code is correct, there must be something going on elsewhere in your code....

Comment: You should write those 3 arguments in a single style attribute. In stead of using an extra `border-style` .

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/s3yphndp/

Comment: try this `border:none !important; border-top: 3px solid white;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use:

```
a:hover {border-top: 3px solid white; border-right: 0; border-bottom: 0; border-left: 0;}
```

If the regular state of your link uses all four borders, then use 0 for the right, bottom, and left borders if you want only the top border on `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover {
border-top: 3px white;
border-style: solid;
border-bottom: 0px white;
border-right: 0px white;
border-left: 0px white;
```

}
Fixed it. Only appears on the top now. :)

Comment: You can write that code much shorter, see my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
border-style: solid;
border-top: thick double green;
border-left:0;
border-bottom:0;
border-right:0;
```

I think when you use `solid` it draws border on al sides. The above code will actually get rid of the border from all three sides but not the top.